# bash + print all enabled service on linux machine with up-time

Tags: bash, awk, systemd, rhel, systemctl

I created the following simple script in order to give the list of all systemctl service with the uptime

we run the script on our rhel 7.2 machine

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ` systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | awk '{print $1}' `
do
echo -e $i
systemctl status $i | grep "Active:" |  awk -F";" '{print (NF>1)? $NF : ""}'
done
```

the script print the following example output

```
accounts-daemon.service
 4 months 4 days ago
appdynamics-machine-agent.service
 9 months 21 days ago
atd.service
 9 months 21 days ago
auditd.service
 9 months 21 days ago
autovt@.service
Failed to get properties: Unit name autovt@.service is missing the instance name.
bluetooth.service
 9 months 21 days ago
chronyd.service
 2 days ago
crond.service
 7 months 25 days ago
dbus-org.bluez.service
 9 months 21 days ago
dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service
 9 months 21 days ago
display-manager.service
 9 months 21 days ago
dmraid-activation.service
 9 months 21 days ago
gdm.service
 9 months 21 days ago
```

while expected output should be as the following

```
accounts-daemon.service      4 months 4 days ago
appdynamics-machine-agent.service       9 months 21 days ago
atd.service       9 months 21 days ago
auditd.service       9 months 21 days ago
autovt@.service
Failed to get properties: Unit name autovt@.service is missing the instance name.
bluetooth.service    9 months 21 days ago
chronyd.service     2 days ago
crond.service      7 months 25 days ago
dbus-org.bluez.service       9 months 21 days ago
dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service       9 months 21 days ago
display-manager.service      9 months 21 days ago
dmraid-activation.service      9 months 21 days ago
gdm.service      9 months 21 days ago
```

the best output that I want to archive is the following , and its much more readable

```
accounts-daemon.service,up 124 days
appdynamics-machine-agent.service,up 234 days
atd.service,up 234 days
.
.
.
```

Comment: It looks like you meant to say ``echo -n``  rather than `echo -e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your script, I added one pipe through `xargs` (before `awk`) a to suppress error outputs, then just use `paste` to get the desired format:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ` systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | awk '{print $1}' `
do
echo -e $i
systemctl status $i | grep "Active:" |  xargs | awk -F";" '{print (NF>1)? $NF : ""}'
done | paste -d, - -
```

---

Update with format "up X days" as output. This checks for the status and if the status has a date regex match (which dead or inactive services or other errors won't have) it will calculate the date difference. Relies on the [`dateutils`-package](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) which is available for most distros. Note that my command uses the `debian` way of calling `dateutils` - this might differ between distros. The `xargs` "hack" is not needed here, due to `sed` and the conditioned change of `$status`.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ` systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | awk '{print $1}' `
do
echo $i
dateregex='20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'
status=$(systemctl status $i | grep "Active:" | sed "s/.*\($dateregex\).*/\1/")
if [[ "$status" =~ $dateregex ]] ; then
    status=$(dateutils.ddiff -f "up %d days" "$status" now)
fi
echo "$status"
done | paste -d, - -
```

Output:

```
syslog.service,up 82 days
systemd-fsck-root.service,up 82 days
systemd-timesyncd.service,up 13 days
triggerhappy.service,up 82 days
wpa_supplicant.service,up 82 days
```

Comment: is it possible to convert the "9 months 21 days ago" to more readable in days as "up 234 day" ?

Comment: @yael - it is with a few detours. See update. Will give "0 days" for services started today.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the required output  by adding sed command

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ` systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | awk '{print $1}' `
do
echo -e $i
systemctl status $i | grep "Active:" |  xargs | awk -F";" '{print (NF>1)? $NF : ""}'
done |sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```